# GA Users overview the graph doesn't match the summary data listed below

Tags: google-analytics

I have an app that I am trying to check the data for and it seems that in GA the data doesn't match. I am in Users Overview viewing 'Active Users'which includes New and Returning. I am looking at a full month worth of data and the days all sum to 4116 active users.
However, the data below the graph says that 2,173 users used this app.

(New to Stack Overflow so can't post image)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gczvy01xvxywbw/Stack%20Overflow%20GA.png

I understand why this might happen if I was using unique visitors across different time frames (http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/standard-metrics-revisited-6-daily-weekly-monthly-unique-visitors/) but if I am not trying to segment them, a visitor should only be counted once regardless of the time frame. It is very unlikely that any user will be using the app overnight so the difference is too large for that to be it.

I have tried searching GA help, but it just tells me what Active users means and I can't find anywhere that specifies how it calculates the graphs and summaries.

Which data is correct? The 4000 from the graph or 2000 from the numbers below?

(I see this kind of discrepancy, though less dramatically, in other places as well, for example I have a list of events categories that say a certain event took place n times but then when I try to get more details the different event actions do not add up to the event total.)

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact the same logic. The graph shows the number of unique visitors for each day. And, the table below shows the unique visitors across the selected date range.

So, when you're adding the number of visitors from the graph, that is equivalent to adding the number of daily unique visitors in Avinash's example.

Comment: Ah, ok, I got it. Because the same user could be active on more than one day, the month view would show that person once, but they would appear on each of the individual days that they were there. It really does feel so counterintuitive - thanks!